# values in ng-model not changing

Tags: angular-ngmodel

I am working with a grid system and grid system contains a form.The values of                form fields remain same with same column number.It is also sortable.Data should be sorted as the rows are sorted.
All the data should be in grid_data.

Kindly answer this problem.
Here is a plunker link

http://plnkr.co/edit/KOYmet8iCAehqesldbPB?p=preview`plunker   link`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work for the `Class` input.  [Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/szsqpQCyEVsfxNqtLhVb?p=preview)

Basically, I created a object to share the class values:

```
$scope.field_values = {
          "class":{"type":"text","title":"Class","desc":"Insert an additional class(es) (separateb by comma) for more personalization.","value":"blah"}

        };
```

I put an initial `"value":"blah"` which you can change yourself.
Then I inserted those values into it your `$scope.fields` object.

```
"class":$scope.field_values["class"],
```

Finally I changed the value of the input and removed the model (because it wasn't necessary).

```
<td><input type="{{val.type}}" value="{{val.value}}"></td>
```

You should be able to do this for each unique field yourself.

Comment: Thanks Wio..
But i want it to be stored in grid_data array with the help of ng-model and these rows are sorable also so data should also be sorted